# Set new value by attribute using dataframe's iloc

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to set new value by attribute using dataframe's iloc, but failed.
I don't know why, maybe it has been deprecated..

```
# make dataframe which contains vending machine location and demand
df = pd.DataFrame({"latitude":np.random.normal(depot_latitude, 0.007, customer_count), 
                   "longitude":np.random.normal(depot_longitude, 0.007, customer_count), 
                   "demand":np.random.randint(10, 20, customer_count)})

# set the depot as the center and make demand 0 ('0' = depot)
df.iloc[0,0] = depot_latitude
df.iloc[0,0].longitude = depot_longitude
df.iloc[0,0].demand = 0
```

It throws error:

```
     30 # set the depot as the center and make demand 0 ('0' = depot)
     31 df.iloc[0,0] = depot_latitude
---> 32 df.iloc[0,0].longitude = depot_longitude
     33 df.iloc[0,0].demand = 0
     34 

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'longitude'
```

Comment: The first parameter is the row index, the second is the column index. I think you meant: `df.iloc[0,1] = depot_longitude`, `df.iloc[0,2] = 0` or since index is default with `loc` `df.loc[0, 'latitude'] = depot_latitude` , etc.

Comment: Consider using `iat` instead of `iloc` for a scalar (single element).

Comment: @HenryEcker I tried it but got this warning: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use .iloc to modify a dataframe, if you do that you'll get a warning. You should instead use:

```
df.loc[0,'latitude'] = depot_latitude
df.loc[0,'longitude'] = depot_longitude
df.loc[0,'demand'] = 0
```

'0' is the row indexer and 'longitude',etc. is the column indexer.

If for some reason you want to use numeric column index, then you can do something like:

```
df.loc[0,df.columns[0]] = depot_latitude
```